# Adding delay in few items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just got a little problem. So I've got array of div names and I want to add them class for half a second and then remove in order they are set. So first shows after a second and disappears after half a second, and next after second etc. I loop through array and nothing really happens :/
Please help me with this function :/

```js
function showAndRepeat(){
  for(var z=0;z<clickNext.length;z++){
    console.log(colors[clickNext[z]]);
    setTimeout(function(){$(colors[clickNext[z]]).addClass(colorNames[clickNext[z]])},1000);
    setTimeout(function(){$(colors[clickNext[z]]).removeClass(colorNames[clickNext[z]])},1500);
  }
}
```

Comment: Besides the given answer, the for loop is synchronous and you are setting all `setTimeout` functions to fire simultaneously.  Do like `setTimeout(funct... bla bla, 1000*(z+1))` and `setTimeout( funct... bla bla, 1000*(z+1) + 500)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the jQuery code is working fine. 
Try this:

```
function showAndRepeat(){
  for(var z=0;z<clickNext.length;z++){
    console.log(colors[clickNext[z]]);
    (function(zee){
        setTimeout(function(){$(colors[clickNext[zee]]).addClass(colorNames[clickNext[zee]])},1000);
        setTimeout(function(){$(colors[clickNext[zee]]).removeClass(colorNames[clickNext[zee]])},1500);    
    })(z);
  }
}
```

Simply, create a closure.

`for` loop is a sync operation whereas `setTimeout` is an async. therefore by the time `setTimeout` executes, the `for` loop have already ran and the latest value of `z` is fed into `setTimeout` call.